# Inherit a class from another file produce errors

Tags: python, inheritance

I wrote two simple classes in python. my parent class which is placed in a file called "class_turtle" is :

```
    class LTurtle:
        def __init__(self, line_width):
            self.line_width = line_width

        def forward(self, step_size):
            print(f"Move Forward = {step_size}")

        def rest(self):
            print(f"Turtle is resting right now")
```

My child class is placed under a file called "class_interpreter" uses the LTurtle class. here is my Interpreter class :

```
from class_turtle import LTurtle

class Interpreter(LTurtle):
    def __init__(self, axiom):
        self.axiom = axiom
        self.string = axiom

    def parser(self):
        for char in self.string:
            if char == 'F':
                LTurtle.forward(50)
            else:
                LTurtle.rest()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_interpreter = Interpreter("F")
    my_interpreter.parser()
```

I also put **init**.py file in the folder. I don't know where I should declare line_width to my LTurtle class and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step_size'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called the `forward()` method on the class name which can be done only if the method is static. Since, `forward()` method is a instance method you need an object to call it.

The object `my_interpreter` is an object of class `Interpreter` which is a subclass of `LTurtle`. Hence, using `self` here refers to object `my_interpreter` and inherits the class `LTurtle`.

Hence, you can call the methods of class `LTurtle` with `self` as follows:

```
def parser(self):
    for char in self.string:
        if char == 'F':
            self.forward(50)
        else:
            self.rest()
```

This will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `self.forward(50)` instead of `LTurtle.forward(50)`

Answer (score -4):

use super() which is a pythonic way when doing inheritance.

Instead of writing

```
 LTurtle.forward(50)
```

change it to

```
super().forward(50)
```

Similarly in else block as well.